# I want to know the difference between of 入れ歯 and インプラント

Tags: usage

I want to know different usages between `入れ歯{ば}` and 歯のインプラント . 
Is this two words mean the same or any other different !

Comment: Actually there is a big difference between 入れ歯 and インプラント. These are  related how much money you would like to spend on the indent. See link [ https://www.tg-ic.com/blog/implant/knowledge ]. I'm not sure I'm afraid I have a guts to translate the whole page.

Comment: The difference between these two words is exactly the same difference as between the English words "false teeth" and "implants".

Answer (score 9):

Technically speaking, 「入{い}れ歯{ば}」 ("denture") and 「インプラント」 ("dental implant") are two very different things.　The former is easily removable and the latter, firmly fixed into the jaw bone.

**Informally**, however, it is true that some people use 「入れ歯」 to refer to 「インプラント」 as well because both are "false teeth" in the broader sense.

What you would ***not*** see is the reverse of the above -- calling 「入れ歯」 informally as 「インプラント」.